How to make nested Screens inside of a Drawer.Navigator?
I have my main screen and a sidebar this is the setup in my App.js file:
function StackNavigator() {
    return (
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Welcome">
          <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Publications" component={Publications}/>
          <Stack.Screen name="History" component={History} />
          <Stack.Screen name="About" component={About} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    );
  }
return (
 <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={() => <Sidebar />}>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Main" component={StackNavigator}/>
 </Drawer.Navigator>)

This Drawer/Sidebar opens perfectly fine. However I want to also have a Stack Navigator inside my Sidebar component (the Drawer.Navigator) and this is where the problem lies, here is what I have so far inside my Sidebar componenet...
return (
 <SiderbarStack.Navigator initialRouteName="Settings" >
      <SiderbarStack.Screen name="DownloadManager" component={DownloadManager} />
      <SiderbarStack.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} />
<SiderbarStack.Navigator />
)

As soon as I add this in the Sidebar component, I get this error: ...
Another navigator is already registered for this container. You likely have multiple navigators under a single "NavigationContainer" or "Screen". Make sure each navigator is under a separate "Screen" container.
I have been reading the docs and trying different things, but it's not clear to me how to achieve what I want. I'm starting to think, what I want is not possible, is it?
To be crystal clear...
I want to have screens for each item in my Sidebar/Drawer component appear from within the Sidebar component itself, not the main screen, that is the goal.
In my app I was using React-Router-Native however I just learned development was discontinued so now I'm migrating to React Navigation. With React-Router-Native I could do this. In fact here is a screen recording of how my Sidebar currently is with React-Router-Native, is this impossible/complicated to do with React Navigation? Link to screen recording

